# MVC ViewModel not populating in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to take an input from a text box, replace some strings within it - and return both the original and the replacement strings to the View, and populate two separate text boxes.

My simple view model is:

```
public class WordsToConvert
{
    public string Original { get; set; }
    public string Replacement { get; set; }
}
```

My cshtml file has a form, which is the same form I would like populated when the Post returns to the same view:

```
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Original, 
                  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Replacement, 
                  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

My controller is very simple (just to get started):

```
    // POST: WTC
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult WTC([Bind(Include = "Original,Replacement")] WordsToConvert wordsToConvert)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            wordsToConvert.Replacement = "Test " + wordsToConvert.Original;
            return View(wordsToConvert); // <---- at this point Watch shows wordsToConvert.Replacement as "Test whatever other text"
        }

        return View(wordsToConvert);
    }
```

I can see wordsToConvert.Replacement changing in the Watch window in VS - but when the View displays it again, it's blank.

If I add @Model.Replacement to the view - then I can see the updated "original" with "Test - xxxxx" at the front.

Is there anything I can do to get the Replacement text to show in the replacement textbox/EditorFor?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: If you are sure that `Replacement` property gets set but not displayed in the view, add `autocomplete = "off"` attribute on the `@Html.EditorFor`, probably is from there

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion - I tried that, but it still didn't work - the generated HTML confirmed the autocomplete was off: <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Replacement" name="Replacement" type="text" value="" />

Comment: Try to change `EditorFor` with `TextBoxFor`, maybe there is a bug with the `EditorFor` helper. One other thing you should try is to send the value as well in the Html Helper (it has an overload for this)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a well known gotcha in MVC.

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Will fix the issue.  You can also do it individually if you want to target just one field:

```
ModelState.Remove("Replacement");
```

The reason is complicated, and has to do with a choice the MVC team made to try and do the right thing most of the time for people (but sometimes this is the wrong thing for some people).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx

Comment: I was scratching my head trying to figure this one out as well, didn't know you could do this with `ModelState`. TIL! +1